# Setting GDAL Config in Python

Tags: python, gdal, configuration

I have a python script to grid a shapefile using `gdal.grid()`

The snippet below works fine (please note that certain parameters have already been stored as variables, and that is why I am calling them during the gridding options)

```
gdal.SetConfigOption('CHECK_DISK_FREE_SPACE','FALSE')

rasterDs = gdal.Grid(gridded_raster, 
                     shapefile, 
                     format='GTiff',
                     algorithm='nearest:radius1={cell_size}:radius2={cell_size}:angle=0.0:min_points=0:nodata=0.0', 
                     outputType = gdal.GDT_Float32,
                     width = txextent,
                     height = tyextent,
                     zfield='z')
```

However my issue is this:

```
gdal.SetConfigOption('CHECK_DISK_FREE_SPACE','FALSE')
```

I had thought by setting that, I would not get a disk space error, but even with it I am still getting the error `Free disk space available is 69166292992 bytes, whereas 2101148117816 are at least necessary. You can disable this check by defining the CHECK_DISK_FREE_SPACE configuration option to FALSE.`

Am I setting it wrong??

Comment: Possibly an incorrect error message...? Try [`gdal.SetConfigOption('CHECK_DISK_FREE_SPACE', 'NO')`](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/gcore/tiff_write.py#L2984)  as that's what is used in the gdal tests.

Comment: Maybe something else https://gdal.org/user/configoptions.html: For boolean options, the values YES, TRUE or ON can be used to turn the option on; NO, FALSE or OFF to turn it off.

Comment: I think that you are setting the config option correctly and in line what is used in https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/utilities/test_gdal_grid_lib.py. Maybe you should send mail to gdal-dev mailing list and ask why the disk space check still gets done.

Comment: @user30184 Thank you!